# Is there any shortcut/tool for correcting white space (tabs v spaces) in pubspec.yaml file in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, yaml, pubspec.yaml, flutter-pubspec

I am getting errors while adding dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file in Flutter project.

Is there any tool or IDE/command line shortcut for editing/correcting/validating the White spaces in the pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: Configure your editor to convert tabs to spaces or use a tool like [`expand`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expand) to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

To add a dependency you can do

```
flutter pub add dependencyname
```

For example http package run

```
flutter pub add http
```